# TFS 2015: Updating work item state after a release

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfs-2015

I have a requirement to update work item status to a ready for test state after the first successful release using TFS release management. It seems like there should be a straightforward built in task to do this but I can't see it. My current thinking is

1. Use TFS REST API to query the workitems and update them all using powershell
2. Wrap this up in a powershell task and include in the release definition

This will do the job I reckon. It's yet more powershell in our releases but they are built on a stack of powershell anyway so at least it's well known.

But is there a better (quicker) way to do this? If the answer is a straight 'no' then great - I will accept that answer gladly.

We are on TFS 2015 R4.

Many thanks for any/all help

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no out-of-the-box feature for this by *Microsoft*.

But we still could use some three-party extensions or tasks to handle this situation.

The [**WorkItem Updater task**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater) can update the following work item fields during a build or release:

- **Update the state for workitems linked to a build.**
- Update the assignee for workitems linked to a build.
- Add the build as Development Link to the workitems.

[image]

The limitation is also very obviously, it could only update work items **which be linked  to a build**. Which seems not be a problem, it's also a good behavior track work items during build pipeline.

Otherwise, you have to use the ways mentioned above to update normal work items after/during a Release.

Comment: Thank you for that. Very informative. I don't think the updater task will work for us. When a work item is linked to a build it doesn't mean it is ready for test. We have different builds feeding into a release and the work items are checked in and passed between builds during development.